# How do you prevent restarting machine after critial Windows updates?

Tags: windows, windows-update

After running critical Windows updates, you are required to reboot machine within certain period.
On my Windows Vista, the longest I can pause is 4 hours.

Is there a way to disable reboot proprompt and be done with it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.  The easy way, assuming you're not in a domain, is to edit the local policy through gpedit.msc

It's in Computer Configuration | Administrative Templates | Windows Components | Windows Update and you can change "Re-prompt for restart with scheduled installations".

There are some other settings you can tweak here, including setting AU to download and notify for install instead of just installing.

Comment: This doesn't work on XP Home either, does it?

Comment: Good point about the domain. If WSUS is being used, we're going to hardcode these values via GPO.

Comment: Too right, KBK - long-since have done so for my WSUS/GPO environment.

Comment: @Richard: No, I am not in domain. Thank you for specifying that point.

Comment: @person-b No, it doesn't work on XP Home because you don't have the group policy editor.  You can hack the registry to the same effect - they way I would do it is to examine the wuau.adm file on an XP Pro machine (in notepad) and work out what the registry keys are.

Answer (score 3):

You can also shut down the Windows update service using the commmand
sc stop wuauserv
It will restart with your next reboot.

Comment: Will this work for XP too?

Comment: net stop wuauserv will definitely work on XP

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent registry data (for Home editions) for the *Re-prompt for restart with scheduled installations* group policy setting is:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\windows\WindowsUpdate\AU]
"RebootRelaunchTimeoutEnabled"=dword:00000001
"RebootRelaunchTimeout"=dword:000005a0
```

For the maximum (in group policy) allowed value of 1440 minutes, or 24 hours.
Can make a `.reg` file out of this.

Disabling the timeout defaults it to 10 minutes as the group policy information suggests.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just set the system to download but not install updates.  Then the updates will be installed when you shut the system down (if you allow the install)